# If $\mu\{x\in X\mid |f(x)|\geq M\}<\frac{K}{M^p}$, show that $f$ is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $K>0$ be a constant, $p>1$ and $\mu(X)<\infty.$ Suppose that $\mu\{x\in X\mid |f(x)|\geq M\}<\frac{K}{M^p}$ for every $M>0.$ Show that $f$ is integrable.

I am quite stuck with this. First, I look at the integral:

$$
\int_X|f|d\mu = \int_{|f|\geq M}|f|d\mu +\int_{|f|\leq M} |f|d\mu.
$$

I notice that

$$
\int_{|f|\leq M} |f|d\mu \leq \mu(X)\cdot M<\infty. 
$$

So really the problem boils down to controlling $\int_{|f|\geq M}|f|d\mu .$ I've tried to use Chebysehv's Inequality and even started reading about the Hardy-Littlewood Maximal Theorem with no success.

Any hints?

Comment: Not a hint: you have not used the fact that the assumption is true for *every* $M>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $$\int_X{|f|d\mu}=\int_{X \times \mathbb{R}^+}{1(|f(x)| \geq t)d\mu\otimes d\lambda(x,t)}.$$

Comment: +1. I think I see now that we bound the integral above to get $\int_{X\times \mathbb{R}^+}\frac{K}{t^p}d\mu\otimes d\lambda = \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} K\mu(X) \frac{1}{t^p}d\mu .$ And since $p>1$, this function is in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^+).$